# Como auditar o tener un historial de actividades de los usuarios guardados en mi db usando mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql

me gustaria saber como podria obtener un historial completo de las actividades realizadas por un usuario logeado en el sistema, insert, update, delete.

Tengo varios usuarios ya guardados y cada uno de ellos tienen niveles de accesos diferentes y solo el administrador podra ver las actividades realizadas por los usuarios que esten por debajo de el dentro del sistema.

INSERT:
Necesito saber el momento exacto (fecha y hora) de la accion, el id y el nombre del usuario (estan almacenados en una session en php) , ademas del nombre de la tabla a la que inserto , el id del row.

UPDATE: 
al igual que con el insert necesito saber el momento exacto de la accion,los datos del usuario logeado, el nombre de la tabla donde realizo el update, el id del row actualizado y el o los campos actualizados (tiene que vizualizarse el antes y el ahora).

DELETE: 
Momento exacto , los datos del usuario ya mencionados, la tabla en la que realizo la accion y el row que elimino.

Acepto cualquier sugerencia para mejorar lo que quiero hacer , tengo que auditar unas 15 tablas y en 3 de ellas esta funcionando una transaccion entre persona, empleado y usuario. Es importante que se detalle que hizo el usuario dentro del sistema para tener constancia del uso indebido de este.

De antemano mil gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Igual te pueda servir este video no es mysql pero la idea es la misma https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gxGJy1KCK4

Comment: la respuesta de Dovakiin es la correcta, en mi caso uso procedimientos almacenados que con un trigger almacenan la informacion que indicas https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-call-stored-procedure-from-trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Una manera sería:

1. Contar con una tabla en la base de datos de tu sistema que almacene
   los datos de los eventos, esta tabla no debería de tener
   restricciones de claves (primaria/foráneas). Ejemplo:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE auditorias (
       tipo_evento int4,
       tabla_afectada varchar(32),
       registro_afectado int4,
       descripcion varchar,
       id_usuario int4,
       ip_usuario inet,
       momento timestamp
   );
   ```
2. Creas una función php que se encargue de llenar la tabla auditorias
   con los datos necesarios. Ejemplo:

   ```
   function registra_evento(int $idUsuario, string $nombreUsuario, string $detalle)
   ```

   O si lo prefieres, pasas los argumentos en un arreglo que contenga el id y el nombre del usuario y cualquier otro dato necesario:

   ```
   function registra_evento(array $datosEvento)
   ```
3. Invocas a la función registra_evento, pasándole los argumentos necesarios.
   Obviamente, deberías de invocar a esta función luego de que el
   evento se haya ejecutado satisfactoriamente.

A grandes rasgos, esto sería una manera de hacerlo. Si tu sistema está desarrollado en MVC lo ideal sería crear una clase que se encargue de realizar las auditorías, con las propiedades y métodos necesarios. O, en su defecto, crear una librería/biblioteca o "helper" que realice esta tarea.

Otra manera sería trabajar con funciones y triggers en la base de datos que se ejecuten después de los inserts, updates y deletes en las tablas.

Las funciones [time](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.time.php) y [date](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) de php, te sirven para obtener y formatear, respectivamente, fechas/horas.